# How do you keep appended input fields to remain when the page is reloaded in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was wondering if a user where to click on a button to add another input field and the web page where to refresh how can I have the added input field remain on the web page after the page has been refreshed? If it helps I'm using JQuery and PHP. My JQuery code is located below

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var max_fields = 30;
    var x = 1;

    $('.another-name').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();    

        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
            $(this).closest('li').find('div:eq(2)').append('<input type="text" name="name[]" />');  
        }

    });

    $('.name').on('click', '.delete-name', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();    

        $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Comment: Keep the count in `local.sessionStorage` and use it...

Comment: Excuse my ignorance what do you mean by local storage object fairly new to jquery.

Comment: Do search about it... SO expects questions after fair amount of research and efforts...

Comment: You need to persist the state of your page and use that to re-create this page on refresh. In your case, you can do this by storing the value of `x` in `localStorage` or on your PHP server by making an AJAX call to persist `x` value when it's updated on click.